# Rename or Move a Project Module in a Git Repository and Preserve the History

Tags: git

I'm trying to rename a project and its Modules and put then in different folders. For example:

**companya-module1 to projecta-module1** 
and
**companya-module2 to projectb-module2**

and then put these renamed modules to a different new folders. After all these changes, now I want to preserve the History from the very beginning. Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to rename a directory in the repository or the repository itself?

Comment: You _can't_ always preserve the history across moves/renames of files or folders.  This is a problem in Git, which is why it's probably best to avoid doing it, unless really necessary.

Comment: I want to rename in the Repository and also, I may move all these new renamed project modules to a new Repository

Comment: Remember that the only history in *any* Git repository is the set of commits in the repository. The commits are history; history is nothing but a set of commits, with their implied linkage. If you have all the commits, you have all the history. If not, you don't. That's it: that's all there is. Renaming files does not *destroy* history at all, it just adds new commits with new files. There is no *file* history, there are only *commits*.

Comment: The tricky part of this is that if you run `git log -- <path>`, Git seems to show *file history*. It doesn't: it shows *selected commits*, namely, those commits in which the commit and its parent have *different* versions of the named file. That's *selected commit history* (which exists), not *file history* (which doesn't, but selected commits sure **looks like** file history, doesn't it?). What happens if you rename a file? Well, you'll have to select *different* commits, right?

Comment: Git currently has one rather inadequate built in tool: `git log --follow -- <path>` selects commits that modify the chosen path, but if, while scanning for such commits, Git comes across a commit that, in Git's diff algorithm, *renames* the file, Git changes *which name it's looking for* as it keeps going. It starts looking for the old name, instead of the new name. So that "follows" the file across renames. The issues here are (1) you only get **one file at a time** and (2) Git has to be able to detect the rename.

Comment: There's one other problem. Git normally works *backwards* (from the latest commits, back through older commits), The `--follow` flag works here: you know the *new* name of the file, and run `git log --follow -- <path>` and it finds for you the *old* name of the file. But what if you know the old name, but not the new name? Git is not very helpful in this case. (There are some ways to find out, they're just not very easy, and kind of slow.) But in all cases, it all boils down to: **commits = history** or **want history? keep commits**.

Answer (score 1):

## Moving directories within a repository

`git` has a `mv` command which allows you to move directories around, that preserves the history.

```
git mv companya-module1 projecta-module1
git mv companya-module2 projectb-module2
```

This stages work as `renamed`, and you'll have to commit this change.

## Moving directories to a new repository

You can use `filter-branch` for this, which takes a `directory` within the structure and creates a new commit with only that directory.

```
git clone git://github.com/user/repo.git
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter companya-module1 -- -- all
```

*Note, this will remove the contents of all other files apart from that directory.*

### git subtree split

Finally, `git` have added `subtree-split` to aid this. Use the following to `subtree split` a specific folder in the `project1` repo and create a branch with that work.

```
cd project1
git subtree split -P companya-module1/ -b companya-module1
```

Once you're ready to put that into it's own repo, you pull that branch (locally)  form the `project1` repo and the specified branch.

```
cd ..
mkdir companya-module1
cd companya-module1
git init 
git pull ../project1 companya-module1
```

What you should end up with, is a new directory / repo with the contents of that directory in `project1`.